# Trying to oauth2 with a generic provider using http requests in Ionic2 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have been trying to find a useful library to authenticate with a generic provider using oauth2. I am new to Ionic, and coudln't find a library that could help me accomplish this easily. I also see that most of the libraries are limited to mobile devices so I decided to go the hard way and try to write the code myself. I apologize if the code lucks ugly or awfully wrong. I have done some PHP programming a long time ago and I am trying to get back to programming with this.

I first generated a provider page with the command: ionic g provider MakeHttpRequest.
Here is a what I wrote so far, just the first step in getting the token.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the MakeHttpRequest provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MakeHttpRequest {

constructor
(
public http: Http,
private client_name : string,
private client_id : string,
private client_secret : string,
private end_point : string,
private auth_uri : string,
private redirect_uri : string
) {
    console.log('Hello MakeHttpRequest Provider');
    this.client_name = 'Alex';
    this.client_id = 'lalala';
    this.client_secret = 'lalalalala';
    this.end_point = 'http://www.lalaland.com';
    this.auth_uri = 'https://services.lalaland.com/oauth/authorize';
    this.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/callback';
  }

 public getcode(){
    this.http.get("${this.auth_uri}?client_id=${this.client_id}&redirect_uri=${this.redirect_uri}&response?type=code")
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});

     }


}
```

then imported the class as follows into home.ts:

```
import {MakeHttpRequest} from '../../providers/make-http-request';
```

created the constructor still under home.ts as follows:
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform : Platform, private MakeHttpRequest : MakeHttpRequest)

and created the following function:

```
public button(){

      this.MakeHttpRequest.getcode()
    }
```

then added the button function to the home.html page.

But all I get is an error. Can someone tell me if I'm in the right direction or even close. Any help or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: I used to get an error saying the Login function was empty, now I get all sort of errors saying no providers for MakeHttpRequest

Comment: you have to set MakeHttpRequest  as provider in your component or NgModule..

Comment: So, a few things. Nothing in here is specific to Ionic yet, it's just Angular2. Second... what's your error? We can't help you if we don't know the error. Could be module setup, a component issue, a ton of stuff. Lastly, your big ol' string in the http request should be using ` instead of " if you want to use template literals ${expression}

Comment: @ Suraj Rao Thanks! that did the trick and helped me advance a bit

Comment: what error are you getting? specify in the question

Comment: @Joshua Ojana , the error I used to get was "No providers for MakeHttpRequest           @ everyone now I am getting this error: Can't resolve all parameters for MakeHttpRequest: (Http, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

Comment: @SurajRao I am trying to edit my answer, but cannot seem to be able to do it. I guess that's because I am new. The error I receive is an't resolve all parameters for MakeHttpRequest: (Http, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) I tried moving the all the declarations in the constructor, i.e client name and client_id inside the geocode() function and the app build fine but when I click the button that calls the function I get this error instead:  Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - caused by: self.context.login is not a function. (In 'self.context.login()', 'self.context.login' is undefined)

Comment: that would be a different error in your component. Not this one... also in your get function,to set the string using `${}`, you need to use backticks(the button above the tab key) not double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can't resolve all parameters for MakeHttpRequest: (Http, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

For this issue,
You need to go through [angular dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Since MakeHttpRequest provider is created through DI, all the parameters of the constructor are set by DI. It is able to locate http but cannot set the primitive types. You will have to remove the string parameters and set in `getCode()`

Comment: Thanks for all the help man! I will look into it, I have already tried setting the variables inside the getCode() function, will look into dependency injection Tomorrow. Its 3.35 AM and I'm tired, I guess I'm getting old. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks man, I decided to start it from scratch and your info helped me get it working.